# ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 1

Tags: xgboost, xgbregressor

I'm trying to run this code and cannot understand the issue I am facing.

This code is working just fine:

```
model = joblib.load(MODEL_PATH)
```

But this does not:

```
model = XGBRegressor()
model.load_model(MODEL_PATH)
model.predict(df[features])
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 1

Comment: What line is it failing on, I am assuming on `model.predict(df[features])`? What is `df` defined as? The argument should be a `dmatrix` object that is passed to the `predict`.

Comment: its a dataframe

Comment: `df[features]` does return a `DataFrame` then?

Comment: Yes. It is a dataframe